# fancybox3 скролинг на мобильных

Tags: fancybox, mobile

Дублирую вопрос с англ:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553047/how-to-disable-swiping-fancybox-slides-by-mousemove#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=Simply%20set%20touch%3Afalse%20to%20disable%20touch%20events.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553047/how-to-disable-swiping-fancybox-slides-by-mousemove#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=Simply%20set%20touch%3Afalse%20to%20disable%20touch%20events.)

в браузерах на мобильных устройствах нет скролинга, при клике окно закрывается.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.fancybox.open({
            src  : '#your_source',
            type : 'inline',
       
            opts : {
                touch: false 
}
})
```